# The method 'when' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, riverpod

I'm trying to do authentication using Riverpod `StateNotifier` and `FutureProvider` but I'm facing error when using `when` method facing this error

> The method 'when' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
> Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

even when adding `!` it shows this

> The method 'when' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.⏎Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'when'.

```dart
class MainPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  final state = ref.watch(emailPasswordSignInControllerProvider);

  return state.when(
    data: (state) {
      return state == AuthState.authenticated
          ? const SharedLayout()
          : const LoginScreen();
    },
    error: (error, stackTrace) => const Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text("Error")),
    ),
    loading: () => const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

**here is controller:**

```dart
class EmailPasswordSignInController extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<AuthState>> {
  EmailPasswordSignInController({required this.authRepository})
      : super(const AsyncValue.data(AuthState.notAuthenticated));
  final AuthRepository authRepository;

  Future<void> submit(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      state = const AsyncValue.loading();
      await authRepository.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      state = const AsyncValue.data(AuthState.authenticated);
    } catch (e, st) {
      state = AsyncValue.error(e, st);
    }
  }
}

final emailPasswordSignInControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) {
  final authRepository = ref.watch(authRepositoryProvider);
  return EmailPasswordSignInController(authRepository: authRepository);
});
```

**And this is my repository:**

```dart
class AuthRepository {
  Future<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    String email, 
    String password,
  ) async {
    try {
      final String token;
      final Map<String, dynamic> jsonData;
      final url = Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.9:5000/api/v1/auth/login');
      final response = await http.post(url,
          body: jsonEncode({
            "email": email,
            "password": password,
          }),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
          });
      jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        token = jsonData['token'];
        return token;
      }
      return "error";
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return e.toString();
    }
  }
}

final authRepositoryProvider = Provider<AuthRepository>((ref) {
  return AuthRepository();
});
```

Comment: Stop using StateNotifier, and anything else that wasn't introduced in Riverpod 2.  It'd become more obvious that your state could be nullable because the build method of your Notifier subclass would have to be nullable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this fixed the error:

```
    StateNotifierProvider<EmailPasswordSignInController, AsyncValue>((ref) {
  final authRepository = ref.watch(authRepositoryProvider);
  return EmailPasswordSignInController(authRepository: authRepository);
});
```

Comment: If you got that from my comment a little credit for my time would be appreciated :)

Comment: do you know can i handle the errors coming from my controller , it's logging me anyways , even if there is error@Texv

Answer (score 3):

The error is saying that `state` where you define it by `final state = ref.watch(emailPasswordSignInControllerProvider);` could return a null value. So you can add a null check operator there if you're sure that it won't return null

```
final state = ref.watch(emailPasswordSignInControllerProvider)!;
```

Or instead you can call it conditionally so that if state is returning a null value, it wont perform the .when:

```
return state?.when
```

You also need to define the type of your provider like this:

```
final emailPasswordSignInControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider<EmailPasswordSignInController, AsyncValue<AuthState>>( (ref)
```

Comment: please read the full message i showed the error that appears when adding it

Comment: That's probably because of the null check operator (!). can you try the other solution? if not, try define the type of your provider like this:   final emailPasswordSignInControllerProvider =
        StateNotifierProvider<EmailPasswordSignInController, AsyncValue<AuthState>>(
            (ref)

Comment: with the null check its probably define as <AsyncValue<AuthState>>? hence the error

Answer (score 0):

```
 final state = ref.watch(emailPasswordSignInControllerProvider) ?? "";
```

try using that it will work,or use in that

```
final state = ref.watch(emailPasswordSignInControllerProvider ?? "");
```